# JQuery accordion icon behind text

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, padding

I am using an accordion for the first time, but for some reason it doesn't display correctly. The icon is behind the text and there is no padding on the left.

a minimal example looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>

    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<link type="text/css" href="css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/vendor/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", active: false, collapsible: true, fillSpace: true });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div id="accordion">
        <div>
            <h3>test</h3>
            <div>bla bla bla</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

a screenshot of how it looks for me [can be viewed here](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/513/screenshotocf.png/)

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your markup needs a few tweaks:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">test</a></h3>
    <div>bla bla bla</div>
</div>​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/WP29E/15/